# Proof integration with magento 2.3

Tags: magento, magento2, proof

I've tried useproof, but it doesn't show real customers info, only imaginary ones.

I would like have proof or similar extension for magento 2 site, anybody heard about free or paid extensions without any pixel?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried usetrigger.com?
They offer a very similar functionality but it was built for Magento 2 with e-commerce in mind. Lots of cool triggers you can use to promote products and increase overall order total. 
I hope this helps. 
Donny